# Can I customize Win10 display scale for an individual program

Tags: windows-10, display-settings

I'm using Win10 ver 20H2, build 19042.1348.  I like to run most programs with the display "Scale and Layout" set to 175% but I have one program where doing so cuts off the buttons on the bottom, so I need to run that one at 150%.  Is there anyway to do so without manually going into the Windows settings every time?

Comment: Though I have not tried this, see https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51533.windows-10-build-1803-registry-tweak-to-fix-scaling-for-apps.aspx about changing scaling -- it's unclear to me if it can be set *per* app.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 Scale is system wide and is independent of application.

So you need to either:

(a) adapt to a single scale that fits your needs.

OR

(b) manually change scale as you need to.

I use method (a) on my Windows 10 and Windows 11 machines.